# Can't link gegl libary with cmake

Tags: cmake, gegl

I got the error message:
:-1: Fehler: error: gegl-0.4: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
:-1: Fehler: error: babl-01: linker input file not found: No such file or directory

So the linker cant find the libaries or can't link them for unknown reason.

I have  tried:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(perspective_lines LANGUAGES C)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lm gegl-0.4 babl-01 ")


#export (PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${GIMP_PREFIX}/share/pkgconfig:${GIMP_PREFIX}/lib64/pkgconfig${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:+:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"")

#add_compile_options(  -L/usr/lib64/libm.so -lm -std=gnu11 -v)
find_package(GTK2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTK2_ATK_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${GTK2_CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${GTK2_GDKCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${GTK2_GDK_PIXBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${GTK2_GLIBCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${GTK2_GLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${GTK2_GTK_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${GTK2_PANGO_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories("${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/usr/include/gegl-0.4")
include_directories("${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/usr/include/babl-0.1")

include_directories("${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/usr/lib64")
include_directories("${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.34-2.1.x86_64/cc-base/math")
include_directories("${ROOT_SOURCE_DIR}/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.34-2.1.x86_64/")

find_path(LIBGIMP_INCLUDE_DIR libgimp PATH_SUFFIXES gimp-2.0)
find_library(LIBGIMP_LIBRARY NAMES gimp-2.0 libgimp-2.0 PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
find_library(LIBGIMP_UI_LIBRARY NAMES gimpui-2.0 libgimpui-2.0 PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
find_library(LIBGIMP_WIDGETS_LIBRARY NAMES gimpwidgets-2.0 libgimpwidgets-2.0 PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
include_directories(${LIBGIMP_INCLUDE_DIR})


#find_path(LIBGEGL_INCLUDE_DIR libgegl PATH_SUFFIXES gegl-0.4)
#find_library(LIBGEGL_LIBRARY NAMES gegl-0.4 libgegl-0.4 PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
#include_directories(${LIBGEGL_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

set(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/9;/usr/lib64;/lib64;/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/lib")

set(SOURCES  perspective_lines.c )

add_executable(perspective_lines perspective_lines.c)

target_link_libraries(perspective_lines
  ${GTK2_GLIB_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_ATK_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_CAIRO_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_GDK_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_GDK_PIXBUF_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_GIO_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_GMODULE_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_GOBJECT_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_GTHREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_GTK_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_PANGOCAIRO_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${GTK2_PANGO_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
  ${LIBGIMP_LIBRARY}
  ${LIBGIMP_UI_LIBRARY}
  ${LIBGIMP_WIDGETS_LIBRARY})

target_link_libraries(perspective_lines "/usr/lib64/libbabl-0.1.so")
target_link_libraries(perspective_lines "/usr/lib64/libgegl-04.so")
#target_link_libraries(perspective_lines gegl)

install(TARGETS perspective_lines DESTINATION ~/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins/)
```

This doesn't work also:
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lm gegl-0.4  -L /usr/lib64/libgegl-04.so")

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: `This doesn't work also` so don't use it? `Where is my mistake ?` Your mistake is passing `gegl-0.4` to the compiler, don't do it. || Och my, so many GTK2_*_STUFF. Can't you just single use `GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `GTK2_LIBRARIES`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for your answer.
That was the problem and ... (its embarrassing) a wrong filename:
target_link_libraries(perspective_lines "/usr/lib64/libgegl-0.4.so")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).